# Enlaces o Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Diseño una pagina web, con boostrap, de hecho baje una plantilla. Tengo un menu, Inicio, Nosotros, Equipo, Contactos, etc.

```
<li><a href="#about" >Nosotros</a></li>
```

El problema esta que este menú, hace parte de la plantilla principal, `_Layout.cshtml`. Es decir que cuando estoy en el navegador `../Inicio/Index`, funciona bien el menú. Pero cuando entro a `../Inicio/TerminosyCondiciones`, presiono cualquier titulo de este menú y no funciona.

No sé cómo enlazarlo. Ya probé:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index","Inicio#about")">Nosotros</a></li>

<li><a href="@Url.Content("/Inicio/Index#about")">Nosotros</a></li>
```

¿Me ayudan?

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres considerar agregar un identificador de fragmento, podrías solo hacer:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index","Inicio")#about">Nosotros</a></li>
```

Asimismo, podrías considerar usar `@Html.ActionLink` que tiene un método sobrecargado que recibe como parámetro el identificador de fragmento.

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Nosotros", "Index", "Inicio", null, null, "about", null, null)</li>
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [Método UrlHelper.Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action%28System.String,System.String%29)
- [Método LinkExtensions.ActionLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Gracias por responder
Probe lo que me dijiste y ninguno funciona.
De hecho cuando estoy en la pagina privacidad, ningun link me funciona
El codigo que aparece al inpeccionar la pagina es este
`< href="/#home">Inicio</a>`
`< href="/home">Inicio</a>`
Esto es lo que tengo en el codigo
`<li>@Html.ActionLink("Inicio", "Index", "Inicio", null, null, "Home", null, null)</li>`
 `<li>@Html.ActionLink("Inicio", "Index", "Home")</li>`

Comment: @JuanSeHurtado, creo que entonces no llegué a entenderte. Tu menú está en `_Layout.cshtml` y solo utilizas identificador de fragmento (ejemplo: `<a href="#lugar">Ir a lugar</a>`) para ubicarte en algún lugar de la página actual donde algún nodo tiene un id con dicho identificador (ejemplo: `<h2 id="#lugar">Lugar</2>` ). ¿Estoy en lo correcto? ¿Has verificado que el id existe en algún nodo de la página donde no funciona? ¿Son identificadores de fragmento que usas o es otra cosa?

Comment: Si, son identificadores de fragmento, y funcionan en Index.cshtml, que es donde los identifica, al entrar a otra pagina, como sigue siendo el mismo menu, ejm, privacidad.cshtml, ningun link me funciona, dentro de este menu, hice la prueba poniendo el enlace fuera y funciona perfectamente, no se como resolverlo aun. De todas formas lo que me dijiste me a ayudado mucho.